# Lambda expression for Sorting after logical operation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a POJO with 2 values, `val1` and `val2`. I want to find the difference, sort a collection in ascending and find the value closest to zero.

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private int val1;
    private int val2;
    //getter-setter
}
```

I want to find the difference between `val1` and `val2` and then sort a collection, so the collection looks like

```
List<Data> listOfData;
```

and my current expression looks like

```
listOfData.stream()
          .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.getVal1()-e1.getVal2(),
                        (e2.getVal1()-e2.getVal2())));

Example

Name1      16    67
Name2      10    60
Name3      27    30
Name4      17    13
```

I want the result to be Name3, as it had the smallest difference, how can I achieve this? My query does not sorted accordingly.

I managed to achieve it like this, but I want to convert it to Lambda expression

```
public void sortDifference(List<ResultantRow> tableRows, final boolean asc) {
    Collections.sort(listOfData, new Comparator<Row>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Row row1, Row row2) {
                    int differenceRow1 = difference(row1);
                    int differenceRow2 = difference(row2);
                    if (differenceRow1 > differenceRow2)
                        return asc ? 1 : -1;
                    else if (differenceRow1 < differenceRow2)
                        return asc ? -1 : 1;
                    return 0;
                }

            });
}
```

My difference is

```
return Math.abs(row.getVal1() - row.getVal2());
```

Comment: Take care of overflows. The difference between two arbitrary `int`s may be larger than the `int` value range. If all your values are positive, or are guaranteed to have a small magnitude, it’s not an issue, otherwise it might be necessary to take measurements, e.g. use `long`s to represent the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort your data in ascending order comparing the absolute difference of `val1` and `val2`. For this, you can use [`Comparator.comparingInt(keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-): this returns a comparator that compares the `int` value extracted by the given extractor.

```
Data data = listOfData.stream()
                      .sorted(comparingInt(d -> Math.abs(d.getVal1() - d.getVal2())))
                      .findFirst()
                      .get(); // or return null or throw an exception
```

Since the sort is in ascending order, this will return the data where the absolute difference is the closest to 0.

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to use plain old [`Collections.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) with the corresponding comparator:

```
Data data = Collections.min(listOfData, 
               Comparator.comparingInt(d -> Math.abs(d.getVal1() - d.getVal2())));
```